# How do I filter event count to correctly reflect the total number of events fired?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I recently made a custom report that gives me the name and number of times a PDF file was downloaded on my client's website. However, the *total* number of events is far more than the number of files downloaded. For example, if there were only 10 files downloaded... the total number doesn't reflect this; it shows me 1000 total events instead of the 10 I'm expecting.

I've structured my segment to look like this:

> Include users when: file_download | file extension contains pdf

I use "Link Text" as a dimension to capture the name of the PDF file. This becomes each row of the output table.

I use "Event count" as the metric I use to capture the number of download events for the PDF files.

The first row of the table displays the total (currently inaccurate) number of events in the "Event count" column. After that, the second row shows the file name and the number of times that file was downloaded in the specified time period.

How can I ensure I get the correct number of download events to show up in my report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the first row (which is a total count of ALL events that are tracked via Google Analytics 4), add a filter that checks the exact name of the event. In this case, it's `file_download`.